# Best way to approach recursion in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, recursion

I have been mostly programming in Python. And this year, I learned how to do recursion using it.

A really good technique my prof taught me is to use list comprehensions like so:

```
def list_all(obj):  

    if not isinstance(obj, list):  
        return [obj]  
    else:  
        return sum([list_all(x) for x in obj], [])
```

Now that I am using JS more and more instead of Python, I am wondering what are specific built-in functions you can use in the language to help with recursion. I know that list comprehension are deprecated in JavaScript, so obviously I can't use them anymore. Would map or filter be good substitutes for list comprehensions in tackling recursion? If not, then what?

Comment: *"I know that list comprehension are deprecated in JavaScript"* - Who told you that?! When did we ever have list comprehensions and why would they ever be deprecated!?

Comment: @AndrewLi: `[for (x of [1,2,3]) x*x]` - try this in your Firefox console ;)

Comment: @georg I understand that future ES versions are implementing list comprehensions but they're not standardized. The problem is the OP claims that they've existed before as a standard and have become deprecated which is not true.

Comment: @AndrewLi: this isn't correct either, comprehensions were there long before 2015, they were planned for the abandoned ES4 (2007).

Comment: The "deprecation" statement is wrong. It's more that it is not recommended as it is not *standard* to use per the MDN doc: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Array_comprehensions. That's about it.

Comment: @georg Ah, I see. I wasn't aware of that. Thanks for the information

Comment: Your prof's "really good technique" is not really good at all: it's a violation of Python's duck-typing principle, and does not handle iterables that are not lists, e.g., strings, tuples or generators.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1952464/in-python-how-do-i-determine-if-an-object-is-iterable

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Array comprehensions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Array_comprehensions#Differences_to_the_older_JS1.7.2FJS1.8_comprehensions) were proposed and implemented by Mozilla as a part of their "Javascript 1.7" initiative (support of then-upcoming and later abandoned ES4) back in 2007, unfortunately they didn't make their way to the current standard (surely, something like `Object.getOwnPropertySymbolsOrSomeOtherUnreadableMess()` is much more important in terms of redability and efficiency). So, in JS you have to resort to `.map` for this kind of stuff:

```
let list_all = obj => {
   if (!Array.isArray(obj))
        return [obj];
    else
        return [].concat(...obj.map(list_all))
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In JavaScript you can indeed use Array prototype methods like `.map()`, `.reduce()`, `.some()`, `.every()`, `.filter()`, to get things done, also recursive calls on arrays. In ES6 the spread syntax (much like the `*` in Python) allows to turn arrays into function arguments. In JavaScript arrays are concatenated with the `.concat()` method instead of Python's `+`, and the ternary operator is used more often than  the `... if ... else ...` operator in Python.

Here is the ES6 code that does what your example Python script does:

```js
function flattenArray(obj) {
    return Array.isArray(obj) 
        ? [].concat(...obj.map(flattenArray)) 
        : [obj];
}
// Sample call:
var res = flattenArray([1,[2,3],[4,[5,6],7],8]);

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

Well this is a really broad question, but in general, JavaScript lends itself to some very practical functional solutions. In the code below, I've defined `flatten` as a very simple recursive procedure that does a simple case analysis on the head of an Array. To me, this reads better than `[].concat` examples that are provided in other answers - also, there's nothing wrong with `Array.prototype.map` but I don't think there's any gain in using it here.

```js
const flatten = ([x,...xs]) => {
  if (x === undefined)
    return []
  else if (x.constructor === Array)
    return [...flatten(x), ...flatten(xs)]
  else
    return [x, ...flatten(xs)]
}

let result = flatten([1,[2,3],[4,[5,6],7],8])

console.log(result)
// [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 ]
```

But, if you want a more in-depth answer, I'd look at an answer I posted here:

- [*Merge/flatten an array of arrays in JavaScript*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39026201/633183)

I have a couple other answers about recursion and array operations that might be useful to you

- [*How to compare arrays in JavaScript*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34256998/633183)
- [*Is there a mechanism to loop x times in ES6 (ECMAScript 6) without mutable variables?*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30452949/633183)
- [*ES6: Merge two arrays into an array of objects*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39711556/633183)
- [*Merge two object in an array*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38858508/633183)

I hope you find these helpful. If you have any questions, let me know.